# Execute/invoke user-space program, and get its pid, from a kernel module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I checked out [Kernel APIs, Part 1: Invoking user - space applications from the kernel](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-user-space-apps/), and [Executing a user-space function from the kernel space - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246636/executing-a-user-space-function-from-the-kernel-space) - and here is a small kernel module, `callmodule.c`, demonstrating that:

```
// http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/code/usermodehelper.c

#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>

static int __init callmodule_init(void)
{
    int ret = 0;
    char userprog[] = "/path/to/mytest";
    char *argv[] = {userprog, "2", NULL };
    char *envp[] = {"HOME=/", "PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin", NULL };

    printk("callmodule: init %s\n", userprog);
    /* last parameter: 1 -> wait until execution has finished, 0 go ahead without waiting*/
    /* returns 0 if usermode process was started successfully, errorvalue otherwise*/
    /* no possiblity to get return value of usermode process*/
    ret = call_usermodehelper(userprog, argv, envp, UMH_WAIT_EXEC);
    if (ret != 0)
        printk("error in call to usermodehelper: %i\n", ret);
    else
        printk("everything all right\n");
        return 0;
}

static void __exit callmodule_exit(void)
{
    printk("callmodule: exit\n");
}

module_init(callmodule_init);
module_exit(callmodule_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

... with `Makefile`:

```
obj-m += callmodule.o

all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

When I run this via `sudo insmod ./callmodule.ko && sudo rmmod callmodule`, I get in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Feb 10 00:42:45 mypc kernel: [71455.260355] callmodule: init /path/to/mytest
Feb 10 00:42:45 mypc kernel: [71455.261218] everything all right
Feb 10 00:42:45 mypc kernel: [71455.286131] callmodule: exit
```

... which apparently means all went fine. (Using Linux 2.6.38-16-generic #67-Ubuntu SMP)

My question is - how can I get the PID of the process instantiated from a kernel module? Is there a similar process other than `call_usermodehelper`, that will allow me to instantiate a user-space process in kernel space, and obtain its pid?

---

Note that it may not be possible to use `call_usermodehelper` and get the instantiated process PID:

[Re: call_usermodehelper's pid ? — Linux Kernel Newbies](http://www.spinics.net/lists/newbies/msg19075.html)

> > > I want to create a user space process from within
> > >       a kernel module, and be able to kill it, send signals
> > >       to it, etc...
> > >
> > > can I know its pid ?
>
> No, you can't. But since inside the implementation the pid is known,
>   patch that makes it available would not be too hard (note, that errors
>   are always negative in kernel and pids are positive, limited to 2**16).
>   You would have to modify all callers that expect 0 on success though.

I poked around the sources a bit, and it seems ultimately there is a call chain: `call_usermodehelper` -> `call_usermodehelper_setup` -> `__call_usermodehelper`, which looks like:

```
static void __call_usermodehelper(struct work_struct *work)
{
    struct subprocess_info *sub_info =
        container_of(work, struct subprocess_info, work);
    // ...
    if (wait == UMH_WAIT_PROC)
        pid = kernel_thread(wait_for_helper, sub_info,
                    CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES | SIGCHLD);
    else
        pid = kernel_thread(____call_usermodehelper, sub_info,
                    CLONE_VFORK | SIGCHLD);
...
```

... so a PID of a kernel thread is used, but it is saved nowhere; also, neither `work_struct` nor `subprocess_info` have a `pid` field (`task_struct` does, but nothing here seems to use `task_struct`). Recording this pid would require changing the kernel sources - and as I'd like to avoid that, this is the reason why I'm also interested in approaches other than `call_usermodehelper` ...

Comment: I wish someone could explain what exactly in this question is "off-topic": it's about Linux Kernel, is that not on-topic enough for "Unix & Linux" Stack Exchange???? But I've been around enough to know it's a wasted effort, when you're under closevote fire... At least maybe someone can suggest if there is a more appropriate Stack site to move this to, etc - but again, I've around long enough.

Comment: My comments from the U&L chatroom: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13687673#13687673

Comment: Also from here - thanks @slm ; if I somehow had that move explanation when the posting was moved, I certainly would not have been whining as much as I did in my above comment `:)` ... Cheers!

Comment: Could you give us the reason why you need the PID? There may be other ways to achieve what you're trying to do... or not ;-)

Comment: Thanks, @ChristopheAugier - basically, I'm trying to solve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629045/capturing-user-space-assembly-with-ftrace-and-kprobes-by-using-virtual-address - and for now, I thought I could code a kernel module that spawns a user process, "pauses" it, retrieves the absolute address of its `main` and sets it up as `kprobe` in `ftrace`. resumes the user process and then gets out of the way. Of course, to do this, first I'd have to get the PID of the spawned process, which is what this question is about. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

A tentative answer from my understanding of the implementation in [kmod.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/kmod.c).

If you look at the code of `call_usermodehelper` you will see it calls `call_usermodehelper_setup` and then `call_usermodehelper_exec`.

`call_usermodehelper_setup` takes as parameter an init function that will be executed just before the `do_execve`. I believe the value of `current` when the init function gets executed will get you the `task_struct` of the user process.

So to get the pid you will need to:

1. Copy the implementation of `call_usermodehelper` in your code.
2. Define an init function that you will pass as parameter to `call_usermodehelper_setup`.
3. In the init function retrieves the current `task_struct` and in turn the PID.

Comment: Many thanks for that, @ChristopheAugier - I was halfway through my answer posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21684898/277826) when I saw your answer, so I first finished that... That answer uses `pid_task(find_vpid(...` to get the `task_struct` from pid, but probably retrieving the `task_struct` directly as you suggest would be better, I guess? I'd still be interested if there is a more straightforward way to do this, though... Thanks again - cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Well, this was tedious... Below is a rather hacky way to achieve this, at least on my platform, as `callmodule.c` (same Makefile as above can be used). As I cannot believe that *this* is the way this should be done, more proper answers are still welcome (hopefully, also, with a code example I could test). But at least, it does the job as a kernel module only - without the need to patch the kernel itself - for the 2.6.38 version, which was quite important to me.

Basically, I copied all functions (renamed with a "B" suffix), until the point where the PID is available. Then I use a copy of `subprocess_info` with an extra field to save it (although that is not strictly necessary: in order not to mess with function signatures in respect to return value, I have to save the pid as a global variable anyway; left it as an exercise). Now, when I run `sudo insmod ./callmodule.ko && sudo rmmod callmodule`, in `/var/log/syslog` I get:

```
Feb 10 18:53:02 mypc kernel: [ 2942.891886] callmodule: > init /path/to/mytest
Feb 10 18:53:02 mypc kernel: [ 2942.891912] callmodule: symbol @ 0xc1065b60 is wait_for_helper+0x0/0xb0
Feb 10 18:53:02 mypc kernel: [ 2942.891923] callmodule: symbol @ 0xc1065ed0 is ____call_usermodehelper+0x0/0x90
Feb 10 18:53:02 mypc kernel: [ 2942.891932] callmodule:a: pid 0
Feb 10 18:53:02 mypc kernel: [ 2942.891937] callmodule:b: pid 0
Feb 10 18:53:02 mypc kernel: [ 2942.893491] callmodule: : pid 23306
Feb 10 18:53:02 mypc kernel: [ 2942.894474] callmodule:c: pid 23306
Feb 10 18:53:02 mypc kernel: [ 2942.894483] callmodule: everything all right; pid 23306
Feb 10 18:53:02 mypc kernel: [ 2942.894494] callmodule: pid task a: ec401940 c: mytest p: [23306] s: runnable
Feb 10 18:53:02 mypc kernel: [ 2942.894502] callmodule: parent task a: f40aa5e0 c: kworker/u:1 p: [14] s: stopped
Feb 10 18:53:02 mypc kernel: [ 2942.894510] callmodule: - mytest [23306]
Feb 10 18:53:02 mypc kernel: [ 2942.918500] callmodule: < exit
```

One of the nasty problems here, is that once you start copying functions, at a certain time you come to a point, where kernel functions are used which are not exported, like in this case `wait_for_helper`. What I did was basically look in `/proc/kallsyms` (remember `sudo`!) to get absolute addresses for e.g. `wait_for_helper`, then hardcoded those in the kernel module as function pointers - seems to work. Another problem is that functions in kernel source refer to `enum umh_wait`, which cannot be used as argument from the module (those need to simply be converted to use `int` instead).

So the module starts the user-space process, gets the PID (*<sub>noting that "[What the kernel calls PIDs are actually kernel-level thread ids (often called TIDs) ... What's considered a PID in the POSIX sense of "process", on the other hand, is called a "thread group ID" or "TGID" in the kernel.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154671/distinction-between-processes-and-threads-in-linux/9154725#9154725)"</sub>*), gets the corresponding `task_struct` and its parent, and tries to list all children of the parent and of the spawned process itself. So I can see that `kworker/u:1` is typically the parent, and it has no other children than `mytest` - and since `mytest` is very simple (in my case, just a single write to disk file), it spawns no threads of its own, so it has no children either.

I encountered a couple of Oopses which required a reboot - I think they are solved now, but just in case, caveat emptor.

Here is the `callmodule.c` code (with some notes/links at end):

```
// callmodule.c with pid, url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21668727/

#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/slab.h> //kzalloc
#include <linux/syscalls.h> // SIGCHLD, ... sys_wait4, ...
#include <linux/kallsyms.h> // kallsyms_lookup, print_symbol

// global variable - to avoid intervening too much in the return of call_usermodehelperB:
static int callmodule_pid;

// >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

// modified kernel functions - taken from
// http://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/linux+v2.6.38/+save=include/linux/kmod.h
// http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.38/+save=kernel/kmod.c

// define a modified struct (with extra pid field) here:
struct subprocess_infoB {
    struct work_struct work;
    struct completion *complete;
    char *path;
    char **argv;
    char **envp;
    int wait; //enum umh_wait wait;
    int retval;
    int (*init)(struct subprocess_info *info);
    void (*cleanup)(struct subprocess_info *info);
    void *data;
  pid_t pid;
};

// forward declare:
struct subprocess_infoB *call_usermodehelper_setupB(char *path, char **argv,
                          char **envp, gfp_t gfp_mask);

static inline int
call_usermodehelper_fnsB(char *path, char **argv, char **envp,
            int wait, //enum umh_wait wait,
            int (*init)(struct subprocess_info *info),
            void (*cleanup)(struct subprocess_info *), void *data)
{
    struct subprocess_info *info;
    struct subprocess_infoB *infoB;
    gfp_t gfp_mask = (wait == UMH_NO_WAIT) ? GFP_ATOMIC : GFP_KERNEL;
  int ret;

  populate_rootfs_wait(); // is in linux-headers-2.6.38-16-generic/include/linux/kmod.h

    infoB = call_usermodehelper_setupB(path, argv, envp, gfp_mask);
  printk(KBUILD_MODNAME ":a: pid %d\n", infoB->pid);
  info = (struct subprocess_info *) infoB;

    if (info == NULL)
        return -ENOMEM;

    call_usermodehelper_setfns(info, init, cleanup, data);
  printk(KBUILD_MODNAME ":b: pid %d\n", infoB->pid);

  // this must be called first, before infoB->pid is populated (by __call_usermodehelperB):
  ret = call_usermodehelper_exec(info, wait);

  // assign global pid here, so rest of the code has it:
  callmodule_pid = infoB->pid;
  printk(KBUILD_MODNAME ":c: pid %d\n", callmodule_pid);

    return ret;
}

static inline int
call_usermodehelperB(char *path, char **argv, char **envp, int wait) //enum umh_wait wait)
{
    return call_usermodehelper_fnsB(path, argv, envp, wait,
                       NULL, NULL, NULL);
}

/* This is run by khelper thread  */
static void __call_usermodehelperB(struct work_struct *work)
{
    struct subprocess_infoB *sub_infoB =
        container_of(work, struct subprocess_infoB, work);
    int wait = sub_infoB->wait; // enum umh_wait wait = sub_info->wait;
    pid_t pid;
    struct subprocess_info *sub_info;
  // hack - declare function pointers, to use for wait_for_helper/____call_usermodehelper
  int (*ptrwait_for_helper)(void *data);
  int (*ptr____call_usermodehelper)(void *data);
  // assign function pointers to verbatim addresses as obtained from /proc/kallsyms
  ptrwait_for_helper = (void *)0xc1065b60;
  ptr____call_usermodehelper = (void *)0xc1065ed0;

  sub_info = (struct subprocess_info *)sub_infoB;

    /* CLONE_VFORK: wait until the usermode helper has execve'd
     * successfully We need the data structures to stay around
     * until that is done.  */
    if (wait == UMH_WAIT_PROC)
        pid = kernel_thread((*ptrwait_for_helper), sub_info, //(wait_for_helper, sub_info,
                    CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES | SIGCHLD);
    else
        pid = kernel_thread((*ptr____call_usermodehelper), sub_info, //(____call_usermodehelper, sub_info,
                    CLONE_VFORK | SIGCHLD);

  printk(KBUILD_MODNAME ": : pid %d\n", pid);
  // grab and save the pid here:
  sub_infoB->pid = pid;
    switch (wait) {
    case UMH_NO_WAIT:
        call_usermodehelper_freeinfo(sub_info);
        break;

    case UMH_WAIT_PROC:
        if (pid > 0)
            break;
        /* FALLTHROUGH */
    case UMH_WAIT_EXEC:
        if (pid < 0)
            sub_info->retval = pid;
        complete(sub_info->complete);
    }
}

/**
 * call_usermodehelper_setup - prepare to call a usermode helper
 */
struct subprocess_infoB *call_usermodehelper_setupB(char *path, char **argv,
                          char **envp, gfp_t gfp_mask)
{
    struct subprocess_infoB *sub_infoB;
    sub_infoB = kzalloc(sizeof(struct subprocess_infoB), gfp_mask);
    if (!sub_infoB)
        goto out;

    INIT_WORK(&sub_infoB->work, __call_usermodehelperB);
    sub_infoB->path = path;
    sub_infoB->argv = argv;
    sub_infoB->envp = envp;
  out:
    return sub_infoB;
}

// <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

static int __init callmodule_init(void)
{
    int ret = 0;
  char userprog[] = "/path/to/mytest";
    char *argv[] = {userprog, "2", NULL };
    char *envp[] = {"HOME=/", "PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin", NULL };
  struct task_struct *p;
  struct task_struct *par;
  struct task_struct *pc;
  struct list_head *children_list_head;
  struct list_head *cchildren_list_head;
  char *state_str;

    printk(KBUILD_MODNAME ": > init %s\n", userprog);
    /* last parameter: 1 -> wait until execution has finished, 0 go ahead without waiting*/
    /* returns 0 if usermode process was started successfully, errorvalue otherwise*/
    /* no possiblity to get return value of usermode process*/
  // note - only one argument allowed for print_symbol
  print_symbol(KBUILD_MODNAME ": symbol @ 0xc1065b60 is %s\n", 0xc1065b60); // shows wait_for_helper+0x0/0xb0
  print_symbol(KBUILD_MODNAME ": symbol @ 0xc1065ed0 is %s\n", 0xc1065ed0); // shows ____call_usermodehelper+0x0/0x90
    ret = call_usermodehelperB(userprog, argv, envp, UMH_WAIT_EXEC);
    if (ret != 0)
        printk(KBUILD_MODNAME ": error in call to usermodehelper: %i\n", ret);
    else
        printk(KBUILD_MODNAME ": everything all right; pid %d\n", callmodule_pid);
  // find the task:
  // note: sometimes p may end up being NULL here, causing kernel oops -
  // just exit prematurely in that case
  rcu_read_lock();
  p = pid_task(find_vpid(callmodule_pid), PIDTYPE_PID);
  rcu_read_unlock();
  if (p == NULL) {
    printk(KBUILD_MODNAME ": p is NULL - exiting\n");
    return 0;
  }
  // p->comm should be the command/program name (as per userprog)
  // (out here that task is typically in runnable state)
  state_str = (p->state==-1)?"unrunnable":((p->state==0)?"runnable":"stopped");
  printk(KBUILD_MODNAME ": pid task a: %p c: %s p: [%d] s: %s\n",
    p, p->comm, p->pid, state_str);

  // find parent task:
  // parent task could typically be: c: kworker/u:1 p: [14] s: stopped
  par = p->parent;
  if (par == NULL) {
    printk(KBUILD_MODNAME ": par is NULL - exiting\n");
    return 0;
  }
  state_str = (par->state==-1)?"unrunnable":((par->state==0)?"runnable":"stopped");
  printk(KBUILD_MODNAME ": parent task a: %p c: %s p: [%d] s: %s\n",
    par, par->comm, par->pid, state_str);

  // iterate through parent's (and our task's) child processes:
  rcu_read_lock(); // read_lock(&tasklist_lock);
  list_for_each(children_list_head, &par->children){
    p = list_entry(children_list_head, struct task_struct, sibling);
    printk(KBUILD_MODNAME ": - %s [%d] \n", p->comm, p->pid);
    // note: trying to print "%p",p here results with oops/segfault:
    // printk(KBUILD_MODNAME ": - %s [%d] %p\n", p->comm, p->pid, p);
    if (p->pid == callmodule_pid) {
      list_for_each(cchildren_list_head, &p->children){
        pc = list_entry(cchildren_list_head, struct task_struct, sibling);
        printk(KBUILD_MODNAME ": - - %s [%d] \n", pc->comm, pc->pid);
      }
    }
  }
  rcu_read_unlock(); //~ read_unlock(&tasklist_lock);

  return 0;
}

static void __exit callmodule_exit(void)
{
    printk(KBUILD_MODNAME ": < exit\n");
}

module_init(callmodule_init);
module_exit(callmodule_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");


/*

NOTES:

  // assign function pointers to verbatim addresses as obtained from /proc/kallsyms:
  // ( cast to void* to avoid "warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast",
  // see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941793/what-is-guaranteed-about-the-size-of-a-function-pointer )

// $ sudo grep 'wait_for_helper\|____call_usermodehelper' /proc/kallsyms
// c1065b60 t wait_for_helper
// c1065ed0 t ____call_usermodehelper
// protos:
// static int wait_for_helper(void *data)
// static int ____call_usermodehelper(void *data)
// see also:
// http://www.linuxforu.com/2012/02/function-pointers-and-callbacks-in-c-an-odyssey/


// from include/linux/kmod.h:

//~ enum umh_wait {
    //~ UMH_NO_WAIT = -1,   /* don't wait at all * /
    //~ UMH_WAIT_EXEC = 0,  /* wait for the exec, but not the process * /
    //~ UMH_WAIT_PROC = 1,  /* wait for the process to complete * /
//~ };

// however, note:
// /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.38-16-generic/include/linux/kmod.h:
// #define UMH_NO_WAIT  0 ; UMH_WAIT_EXEC   1 ; UMH_WAIT_PROC   2 ; UMH_KILLABLE    4 !
// those defines end up here, regardless of the enum definition above
// (NB: 0,1,2,4 enumeration starts from kmod.h?v=3.4 on lxr.free-electrons.com !)
// also, note, in "generic" include/, prototypes of call_usermodehelper(_fns)
// use int wait, and not enum umh_wait wait ...

// seems these cannot be used from a module, nonetheless:
//~ extern int wait_for_helper(void *data);
//~ extern int ____call_usermodehelper(void *data);
// we probably would have to (via http://www.linuxconsulting.ro/pidwatcher/)
// edit /usr/src/linux/kernel/ksyms.c and add:
//EXPORT_SYMBOL(wait_for_helper);
// but that is kernel re-compilation...

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19360298/triggering-user-space-with-kernel
// You should not be using PIDs to identify processes within the kernel. The process can exit and a different process re-use that PID. Instead, you should be using a pointer to the task_struct for the process (rather than storing current->pid at registration time, just store current)

# reports task name from the pid (pid_task(find_get_pid(..)):
http://tuxthink.blogspot.dk/2012/07/module-to-find-task-from-its-pid.html

  // find the task:
    //~ rcu_read_lock();
  // uprobes uses this - but find_task_by_pid is not exported for modules:
    //~ p = find_task_by_pid(callmodule_pid);
    //~ if (p)
        //~ get_task_struct(p);
    //~ rcu_read_unlock();
  // see: [http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/linux/kernel/1260996 find_task_by_pid() problem | Linux | Kernel]

  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408766/make-a-system-call-to-get-list-of-processes
  // this macro loops through *all* processes; our callmodule_pid should be listed by it
  //~ for_each_process(p)
    //~ pr_info("%s [%d]\n", p->comm, p->pid);

  // [https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2008/05/msg00034.html Re: problems for making kernel module]
  // note - WARNING: "tasklist_lock" ... undefined; because tasklist_lock removed in 2.6.1*:
  // "tasklist_lock protects the kernel internal task list.  Modules have no business looking at it";
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002444/list-all-threads-within-the-current-process
  // "all methods that loop over the task lists need to be wrapped in rcu_read_lock(); / rcu_read_unlock(); to be correct."
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208487/kernel-module-that-iterates-over-all-tasks-using-depth-first-tree
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728592/how-can-i-get-the-children-process-list-in-kernel-code
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446239/traversing-task-struct-children-in-linux-kernel
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207160/kernel-how-to-iterate-the-children-of-the-current-process
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262017/linux-kernel-list-list-head-init-vs-init-list-head
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230524/explain-list-for-each-entry-and-list-for-each-entry-safe "list_entry is just an alias for container_of"

*/
```