# In Linux kernel mode, how to execute a user space command

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, kernel-mode, userspace

I hook execve in kernel mode(change system_call_table entry __NR_execve to my function). I want to check the ELF's assembly code. If it harmful, I'll return directly without executing it.

I am writing a linux module. In Linux kernel mode, I want to use objdump to disassembly the ELF file.
I want to go user mode to execute objdump, and go back to kernel mode. Is this possible?
Thank you.

Comment: Sounds strange. What do you need this for? Maybe it can be done in another way, without running user-space application from kernel. So please explain us the whole task so perhaps we can come up with some more appropriate and elegant solution.

Comment: Sam Protsenko, I hook execve in kernel mode(change system_call_table entry __NR_execve to my function). I want to check the ELF's  assembly code. If it harmful, I'll return directly without executing it. Do you have any other idea to do this?

Comment: It would be much more better if you can do the same in user-space. Just doesn't sound like kernel task to me. But I may be mistaken.

Comment: How to hijack execve in user space? LD_PRELOAD doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can split your project into two parts: kernel module and user-space application. So you can hook `execve()` in kernel, then tell your application about hook triggered, then do disassembling and checking in your application, send computed result back to kernel module, and then either continue or break `execve()` execution.

If you still want to run `objdump` from kernel -- check out [call_usermodhelper()](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-call-usermodehelper.html).

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21668727/execute-invoke-user-space-program-and-get-its-pid-from-a-kernel-module) related question.

Comment: Thank you very much, Sam Protsenko. This is very helpful. I want to use call_usermodhelper(). I'm going to write a user space script(or C program) to check assembly code, and then send the result (0 or 1) back to kernel. So my next question is, how can I get the value in kernel mode? write to a file?

Comment: You can just run your user-space app as a daemon and don't use `call_usermodhelper()`. Regarding interaction between kernel and user-space: there are a lot of options here. The easiest, perhaps, is to utilize **character device driver** capabilities to exchange some data between kernel and user-space. The other possible and easy option -- is to create some **sysfs** file/files in your kernel module, and read/write to them from user-space app.

Comment: Sam Protsenko, could you give me an example of transfer data from user space to kernel space? Thank you very much.

Comment: The thing is, there is a lot of options how you can implement such a transfer. Ideally you should choose it for your particular case. If you don't have much of experience in kernel development -- I'd recommend you to look into **miscellaneous character device** API Next particular function can be useful: `misc_register()`, `misc_deregister()`, `simple_read_from_buffer()`, `simple_write_to_buffer()`. Once you registered misc char device and implemented read/write file operations in kernel, you will be able to read/write to corresponding file in `/dev` directory to talk with your kernel module.

Comment: Look [here](http://www.linuxvoice.com/be-a-kernel-hacker/) and [here](https://github.com/svijaykr/eudyptula/blob/master/task06/hello-world.c) for examples (I just googled by "misc_register simple_read_from_buffer" and chose what I liked most).